# FTP HAProxy not working on port 21 but 23

Tags: debian, ftp, haproxy, passive

I have a simple HAProxy config; frontend on port 21, backend to one ftp-server.
the ftp-server is in passive mode, therefore once a control connection is established the data connection is handled by the backend server.

Now the problem: if I use **port 21** in the frontend it is **not working**. 
If I use **port 23** it is **working**. 
There is nothing else listening on port 21 (netstat -tulpn | grep :21)

here is my haproxy config I have replaced my server IP with

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    # user haproxy
    # group haproxy
    maxconn 2000

defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

frontend haproxy_in
        bind *:21
        default_backend haproxy_ftp

backend haproxy_ftp
        balance roundrobin
        mode tcp
        server ftp1 <serverip>:21 check
```

status: active (running)

syslog from restart:

```
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname systemd[1]: Stopping HAProxy Load Balancer...
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname haproxy-systemd-wrapper[21314]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: SIGTERM -> 21316.
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname haproxy-systemd-wrapper[21314]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=143
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname systemd[1]: haproxy.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 16 08:28:40 hostname haproxy-systemd-wrapper[22090]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rebooted the system.
This is a very unsatisfying answear.
There where probably open connections to port 21 where previously an ftp-server was listening.